# Close vs strong linkage

Tags: differences

When two phenomena are interrelated, the linkage between them may be characterized as either strong or close. Google suggests that the two are equally common in both academic and non-academic contexts. Are the two completely synonymous, or are there nevertheless differences between them (as slight as they might be) in meaning or linguistic register?

*A few examples from Google Scholar:
 1. "strong linkage between inequality and political violence" 
 2. "close linkage between cultural ideals of masculinity and femininity and
    sexual expression." 
 3. a strong linkage between cultural values and constitutional choices"
 4. "close linkage between social rank and access to resources"*

Comment: What phenomena are you referring to? Can you write or quote an example sentence where the phrase would be used?

Comment: A few examples from Google Scholar: (1) "strong linkage between inequality and political violence" (2) "close  linkage  between  cultural  ideals  of  masculinity  and femininity and sexual expression." (3) " a strong linkage between cultural valuesand constitutional choices" (4) "close linkage between social rank and access to resources"

Comment: You can edit your question as the comment is not intended to last long.

Comment: I believe that the two are synonymous.

Answer (score 2):

It's really a matter of preference for the writer. In the examples that you provide in your question, both "close" and "strong" mean the same thing.